Calculate audio tokens for Openai's realtime API
I am trying to find a way to calculate billable audio tokens for my Realtime API usage on OpenAI's API.
I can see aggregated usage costs on OpenAi's dashboard for my api keys but would like to get more granular data on a per API request.

There is no way to calculate the token number exactly. But you can do a rough calculation by the length of audio.

Audio input costs approximately 6¢ per minute; Audio output costs approximately 24¢ per minute.

You can find it here https://openai.com/api/pricing/

You can try manipulate a event called by: 'response.done', this will be triggered aways by the model, after audio/transcription response, link to de docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/realtime-server-events/response/done
You will receive something like these:
{
"event_id": "event_3132",
"type": "response.done",
"response": {
    "id": "resp_001",
    "object": "realtime.response",
    "status": "completed",
    "status_details": null,
    "output": [
        {
            "id": "msg_006",
            "object": "realtime.item",
            "type": "message",
            "status": "completed",
            "role": "assistant",
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Sure, how can I assist you today?"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "usage": {
        "total_tokens":275,
        "input_tokens":127,
        "output_tokens":148,
        "input_token_details": {
            "cached_tokens":384,
            "text_tokens":119,
            "audio_tokens":8,
            "cached_tokens_details": {
                "text_tokens": 128,
                "audio_tokens": 256
            }
        },
        "output_token_details": {
          "text_tokens":36,
          "audio_tokens":112
        }
    }
}
}

Or maybe you can try establishing a logic based on this event, calculating the delta between the remaining and the total.:

Link to the docs:
https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/realtime-server-events/rate_limits
